# How to write every "fault" in new line in a text file with date and time?

Tags: c#

My text file becomes overwritten with a new value using the code below. Now, how do I write every new value to a new line with date and time? Thanks

```
string tot = Convert.ToString(i);
if (some_condition)
{
  i++;
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\TotalFaults.txt", tot);
}
```

Comment: not really an answer, more a suggestion. I would use something like `Log4Net` as this manages file creation/append etc. Also, you can add config items to flag up issues, warnings, errors etc, thereby allowing you to test for conditions AND log errors

Comment: What I am trying to do is to create a log file with errors if they occur. The important thing is to have every error in a new row with date and time... As Fubo's answer below using AppendAllText will do a part of what I need.

Comment: Mocke - i honestly feel that you are not treating the errors with any rigour by merely recording that an error occurred at a specific time and numbering it - sorry :(

Comment: I'll post a new better described question.

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText
```

with

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText
```

to append the specified string to the file

Comment: This will write all values in the same row like 0123456... How to write like this 0 date and time
       1 date and time
and so on

Comment: you didn't mention multiple values in your question. update your question or start a new one

Comment: alright, i'll post a new question with better description.